# Display long string with left and right and dots middle

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a long word, such as: fooxxxxxxxxxxxxxbar

In a cell of Libreoffice Calc, how can I display this value like this "foo...bar" with the 3 dots in the middle?

Comment: If you want to display a shortened string in an adjacent cell, then a formula like `=IF(LEN(A2)>6;LEFT(TRIM(A2);3)&"..."&RIGHT(TRIM(A2);3);A2)` will do the job. If you want to format a text string directly in a cell without changing the original value, but only by changing the display - no, there is no way.

Answer (score 1):

*Okay, I'm posting this solution, but I don't recommend using it - it's just an example that you can code anything.*

The [**format of the cell**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/05020000.html) is responsible for displaying the contents of the cell.

If we use the ability [**to add arbitrary text**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/01/05020301.html?&DbPAR=CALC&System=WIN#:%7E:text=the%20correct%20result.-,Text%20and%20Text,-To%20include%20text) to the format code, we can perform the following trick:

[image: Format cell]

Now let's try to make Calc automatically create and apply the necessary formats. We use a somewhat simplified code for the `FindCreateNumberFormatStyle()` function from [**Listing 5.38: Create a number format style**](http://www.pitonyak.org/AndrewMacro.odt).

```
Function FindCreateNumberFormatStyle (sFormat As String)
Rem Simplified code from Listing 5.38. Create a number format style.
Rem See http://www.pitonyak.org/AndrewMacro.odt
Dim oDoc As Object, oFormats As Object, formatNum As Integer
Dim aLocale As New com.sun.star.lang.Locale
  oDoc = ThisComponent
  oFormats = oDoc.getNumberFormats()
  formatNum = oFormats.queryKey (sFormat, aLocale, TRUE)
  If (formatNum = -1) Then
    formatNum = oFormats.addNew(sFormat, aLocale)
    If (formatNum = -1) Then formatNum = 0
  End If
  FindCreateNumberFormatStyle = formatNum 
End Function
```

With such a tool, we can easily write an event handler for the sheet **Content changed**.

[image: Set Sheet Event]

The handler code could be something like this:

```
Sub onContentChanged(oEvent As Variant)
Dim oCellsString As Variant, oCells As Variant, oCell As Variant
Dim sString As String,  sFormatString As String
    oCellsString = oEvent.queryContentCells(com.sun.star.sheet.CellFlags.STRING)
    oCells = oCellsString.getCells()
    For Each oCell In oCells
        sString = oCell.getString()
        If Len(sString) > 9 Then
            sFormatString = ";;;""" & Left(Trim(sString),3) & "..." & Right(Trim(sString),3) & """"
            oCell.clearContents(com.sun.star.sheet.CellFlags.HARDATTR)
            oCell.NumberFormat = FindCreateNumberFormatStyle (sFormatString)
        EndIf 
    Next oCell
End Sub
```

This will apply a shortened string image to a cell format that contains a string longer than 9 characters (there is no point in processing a shorter string - the requested display mask already contains 9 characters)

Now, after entering a long string into a cell, the macro will work and the cell format will display a shortened version of the content.

But how to change all the long strings that are already on the sheet? Not a problem - find all cells with text content and follow the same procedure for each of them:

```
Sub formatExistingLongStrings
Dim oSheet As Variant, oRanges As Variant, oRange As Variant
    oSheet = ThisComponent.getCurrentController().getActiveSheet()
    oRanges = oSheet.queryContentCells(com.sun.star.sheet.CellFlags.STRING)
    For Each oRange In oRanges
        onContentChanged(oRange)
    Next oRange
End Sub
```

**Why do I not recommend using this solution?**

First, the format trick won't work for cells containing a line break - for those cells, the format will simply be text and the cell will be displayed at full size.

Second, each line encountered will generate a new custom format. And judging by the fact that searching for the string [***libreoffice remove user-defined formats***](https://www.google.com/search?q=libreoffice+remove+user-defined+formats) does not give a single reasonable result, getting rid of obsolete formats will be extremely difficult - your spreadsheet will swell and inevitably start to slow down.

Comment: Good answer, although it looks like formats *can* be removed by using [XNumberFormats.removeByKey()](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1util_1_1XNumberFormats.html#ad05c457dd440df488a0d3fae325425db). If the number codes are only needed for a few strings that contain a large number of "x"s (might want to do a regex pattern match for that rather than testing only the string length, although maybe that's not easy in Basic), then perhaps this approach is practicable.

Comment: @JimK I could agree with the suggestion to use `.removeByKey()`, but my attempt causes office to crash - hence the wording "***remove procedure is non-trivial***"